# button click check?

Tags: c#

I WANT to find out if a there is a way
to check if a group of buttons are being clicked
for exp. if i have nine buttons and i want to check
to see if any of the nine is clicked like

```
if(button1.text ==""
                                               button2.text ==""
                                               button3.text=="" 
                                               button4.text==""
                                               button5.text=="" )
```

so instead of checking each Individual click we can have it check
nomatter what button is clicked????

Comment: How does the Text property relate to clicking the button

Comment: Call same function on OnClick Event of all group buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit confused about what you are trying to do here, but LINQ is your friend if you want to avoid convoluted if statements

```
//Checks if any button has Text = ""
if (this.Controls.OfType<Button>().Any(b => b.Text == string.Empty))
{

}
```

Comment: "this.Controls" should be replaced with the closest parent to the buttons

Comment: i want to link one event click to a group of nine buttons

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood. Just connect the same click handler to all of them then btn.Click += SomeHandler.... for all of them

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this :-

```
<asp:Button id="b1" Text="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="test" />
<asp:Button id="b2" Text="btn2" runat="server" OnClick="test"/>
<asp:Button id="b3" Text="btn3" runat="server" OnClick="test"/>
<asp:Button id="b4" Text="btn4" runat="server" OnClick="test"/>
```

event handler will be like:-

```
 void test(Object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
      //do something
    }
```